# Interrupt command (ctrl+C) no longer working in VS Code 1.78 terminal on macOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

At the top of every terminal I open is the text:
"*bash: no job control in this shell*"

I don't remember changing anything in VS Code but now I can no longer use 'control + c' to stop stuff in my terminal (like 'npm run dev' and 'node app.js')

Everything still works perfectly in my computer's terminal - it's just VS Code that's having issues.

I haven't tried much because I couldn't really find anything online about this exact issue.  I tried ChatGPT, which told me to add some configurations to my settings.json file, but none of them worked.

Comment: I'm starting to use VScode for the first time, also on Mac, and I'm getting the same issue. Here's a screenshot of what happens when I try to Ctrl+C three times: https://imgur.com/a/9EbCFsq

Comment: yes, nmjk's screenshot is exactly what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is a case of this open issue: [MacOS: "no job control in this shell" #184713](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184713), which is affecting macOS users using VS Code 1.78. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show that you have the issue, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress.

As a current workaround, others have found that the issue does not occur to them after downgrading to VS Code 1.77 or 1.78. [Others have found](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184713#issuecomment-1675862110) that the issue goes away if they put `export PROMPT_COMMAND="set -m"` in one of their bash startup files, such as `~/.bash_profile`.

[It's been suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184713#issuecomment-1672915441) that the issue might be due to use of a missing posix_spawn api in the affected versions.

If you're interested in trying to contribute a fix, the related code is in https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/blob/main/src/unix/pty.cc, and this test would fail on affected OSes: https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty/blob/d6ce76a801f68730f7204b7b27bb21dbf8e63001/src/unixTerminal.test.ts#L123