# Bash job control error in intgrated Vscode terminal on Mac OS

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

A time ago I started receiving the following message when starting a new terminal in VsCode:

> bash: no job control in this shell

And it is very annoying because it does not allow me stopping a job running in terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

I tried re-installing Vscode, I tried to follow the steps that ChatGPT gave me trying to resolve this problem, entering the configuration of VSCode and excluding this, if active `terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell`. I tried using zsh shell, but nothing works and it is very very very annoying.

When I try to stop the job using <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> appears this, after three tries:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/9EbCFsq]

Comment: Open a new terminal, and run `set -m`. Then run `sleep 60` and try to stop it with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Why would you trust ChatGPT to tell you anything true?

Comment: @Philippe, `-m` turns job control on, and is already set by default in an interactive shell connected to a TTY; I think you meant `+m` to turn it off?

Comment: Anyhow -- it's implied that your shell has job control disabled, which you can check for sure with `echo $-`; if that's the case, it might be because VS Code isn't properly emulating a TTY in its terminal, or it might be because the shell isn't being invoked with appropriate arguments / is having inappropriate arguments added; you aren't telling us enough to know for sure.

Comment: This is a pretty well-known issue in Visual Studio Code for macOS: [see GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184837)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **convert** your images of text into actual text? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: actually, a better dup target is probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/76570268/11107541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interrupt command (Control + C) no longer working in VS Code 1.79 terminal on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76244314/interrupt-command-control-c-no-longer-working-in-vs-code-1-79-terminal-on-ma)